# MYSQL doesn't compare big int(20) properly

Tags: mysql, compare, bigint

I'm new to mysql... I have a table 'table1' where a column 'item_no' is bigint(20). When i tried to select a particular row from the table based on the item_no, it doesn't return the exact row. Instead it returns a set of rows that matches first few characters. Why is it so and how my query should be to get the exact row.

```
table1
----------
item_no BIGINT(20) --> Primary key
value VARCHAR(40)
```

I have the following values for item_no in my table

```
item_no                value
----------
10000000161402118444   blah
10000000161402118613   blah
10000000161402118984   blah
10000000161402119080   blah
10000000161402119151   blah
10000000161402119275   blah
10000000161402119680   blah
10000000161402119866   blah
10000000161402119946   blah
```

And this my query

```
SELECT item_no FROM table1 WHERE item_no = 10000000161402119946
```

Expected result

```
item_no
----------
10000000161402119946
```

But my query returned the following:

```
item_no
----------
10000000161402119275
10000000161402119680
10000000161402119866
10000000161402119946
```

I'm unable to figure it out ... Please help me out....

Comment: please read documentation on mysql types. Your integer happens to be just out of range of a signed integer. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers exceed bigint's [limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html).
If you make your field unsigned, then it would work.

```
create table biginttest2 (id bigint unsigned);
```

Comment: but why it didn't show up
`10000000161402119151
10000000161402119080`
Even these two matches the expression..?

Comment: @PrathapB, it's a mystery to me too. I suspect mysql engine tried to match as many binary digits as it could